# Can SqlBulkCopy be used with a SQL Server Compact database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, sqlbulkcopy

I have a live database and a local database and I want to copy a large amount of data in my live database using (`SqlClient`) to my local database (`SqlServerCe` - SQL Server CE database). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have a SqlCeBulkCopy library/Nuget package that you can use:

https://github.com/ErikEJ/sqlcebulkcopy

Sample code:

```
using ErikEJ.SqlCe;

private static void DoBulkCopy(bool keepNulls, IDataReader reader)
{
    SqlCeBulkCopyOptions options = new SqlCeBulkCopyOptions();
    if (keepNulls)
    {
        options = options |= SqlCeBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls;
    }
    using (SqlCeBulkCopy bc = new SqlCeBulkCopy(connectionString, options))
    {
        bc.DestinationTableName = "tblDoctor";
        bc.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I use your library? can I just paste it the directory of my project?

Comment: Add a project with my library to your solution, or use the Nuget package